# I miss the low quality flag

Tags: discussion, flagging

Today I had a feeling while checking the list of possible flags that some flags (for answers) are missing for example I miss the low quality flag ... so what happen to it or where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably just checking on a post that has a positive score; the option to flag a post as VLQ only shows up on posts that have a score of zero or less.

See also relevant MSE posts:

- [Why is the option very low quality sometimes hidden in flag menu?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258895/132874)
- [Why is it not possible to flag an upvoted answer as Low Quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220620/132874)